# How to build this json using .net C#?

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to build a json like this:

```
...
  "conditions": [
      [
        "Language",
        "IN",
        [
          "en"
        ]
      ]
    ]
...
```

I am using this code:

```
new JProperty("conditions", new JArray(new JArray((new JArray("Language", "IN", new JArray(IsEnglish ? "en" : "es"))))))
```

But this one built me a json with one less array.

```
  "conditions": 
      [
        "Language",
        "IN",
        [
          "en"
        ]
      ]
```

I tried to nest this into another JArray but that is not working. Please suggest.

EDIT: This is the whole Json making statement

```
 JObject json = new JObject(
           new JProperty("application", pwApplication),
           new JProperty("auth", pwAuth),
           new JProperty("notifications",
               new JArray(
                   new JObject(
                       new JProperty("send_date", "now"),
                       new JProperty("content", new JObject(new JProperty("en", pushContentEnglish), new JProperty("es", pushContentSpanish))),
                       new JProperty("ios_badges", 0),
                       new JProperty("data", new JObject(new JProperty("custom", new JObject(new JProperty("t", notificationType), new JProperty("i", objectId))))),
                       new JProperty("devices", new JArray(strDeviceArray)),
                       new JProperty("conditions", new JArray(new JArray((new JArray("Language", "IN", new JArray(IsEnglish ? "en" : "es")))))
                       )))));
```

Comment: downvoter, care to comment why?

Comment: How many data do you using when you trying to do this ?
I think you using only one data, and the lib, don't understand that you want to make one more array... ?

Comment: @BrunoCasali yes thats the whole point..how to make the lib create one more array

Comment: Can you use Newtonsoft (Json.net)? That would save you a whole heap of code in this case.

Comment: @zaitsman already using the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
new JProperty("conditions", new JArray((JContainer)new JArray("Language", "IN", new JArray(IsEnglish ? "en" : "es"))))
```

And the reason this works is because the [JArray(JArray)](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_1.htm) constructor copies the elements from the JArray parameter to the JArray being constructed, whereas casting it to JContainer (from which JArray inherits) invokes the [JArray(Object)](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray__ctor_2.htm) overload.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Json.Net, why not do:

```
var conditions = new[] { new object[] { "Language", "IN", new[] { "en" } } };
var result = "conditions:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conditions);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..but how to add this property to my main json

Comment: @Lakshay, can you update the post with the entire result that you're looking to achieve (e.g. full format of the resulting json)

Answer (score 0):

I think do you using only one data...

```
"conditions": [
  [
    "Language",
    "IN",
    [
      "en"
    ]
  ]
]
```

but if you try to make one more...

```
"conditions": [
    [
        "Language",
        "IN",
        [
            "en"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "Language",
        "IN",
        [
            "pt"
        ]
    ]
]
```

If you can test this code with more than one data in this expected array... ? You'll tried this?

Comment: @Lakshay, understand now ?!

Comment: i understand your point..but the stupid API wants the data to be a single item in an array..